# Checking for actions on a paused sprite kit scene

Tags: sprite-kit

I have this code here, when I press a button, it pauses the scene. I have an else if statement that when I select another button it will resume it. However I can not do any actions while the scene is paused.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
for (UITouch *touch in touches)
{
    SKTexture * playTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayButtonButton.png"];
    SKTexture * pausedTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PauseButtonButton.png"];

    SKSpriteNode *pause = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"pause"];
    SKSpriteNode *play = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"pausedd"];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];


    if([pause containsPoint:location])
    {
        [berry removeFromParent];
        [pause runAction:[SKAction setTexture:playTexture ] completion:^{
            [self.scene.view setPaused:YES];

        }];


    } else if ([play containsPoint:location]){
        [play runAction:[SKAction setTexture:pausedTexture] completion:^{
            [play removeFromParent];

            [self.scene.view setPaused:NO];

        }];

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
pause.texture = playTexture;
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

No actions needed here.